# Anonymous inner class : Return an instance of an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I am self-learning Java with the book "Thinking in java 4th Edition".

When i come to trying one example from the book, it gives compiler error.

https://github.com/BruceEckel/TIJ4-code/blob/master/examples/innerclasses/Parcel7.java

```
//: innerclasses/Parcel7.java
// Returning an instance of an anonymous inner class.

public class Parcel7 {
  public Contents contents() {
    return new Contents() { // Insert a class definition
      private int i = 11;
      public int value() { return i; }
    }; // Semicolon required in this case
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parcel7 p = new Parcel7();
    Contents c = p.contents();
  }
} ///:~
```

```
.\Parcel7.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    public Contents contents() {
           ^
  location: class Parcel7
.\Parcel7.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        return new Contents() {
                   ^
  symbol:   class Contents
  location: class Parcel7
.\Parcel7.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        Contents c = p.contents();
        ^
  symbol:   class Contents
  location: class Parcel7
3 errors
PS S:\Java Learning\001. Hello> javac .\Parcel7.java
.\Parcel7.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
    public Contents contents() {
           ^
  symbol:   class Contents
  location: class Parcel7
.\Parcel7.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
      return new Contents() { // Insert a class definition
                 ^
  symbol:   class Contents
  location: class Parcel7
.\Parcel7.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
      Contents c = p.contents();
      ^
  symbol:   class Contents
  location: class Parcel7
3 errors
```

Do I miss anything?

Comment: The `Contents` class needs to be on the compiler's class path when you compile. That may mean you are compiling the file containing it at the same time; you may need to tell the compiler where to find the already-compiled class. Without further details, we can't say. And it needs to be imported of it is not in the same package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This anonymous class declaration creates an anonymous class that is a sub-type of the class `Contents`.

Looking at the error, I assume that you do not have a named class called `Contents` defined anywhere. If you already have that class, then it may not have been imported properly.

Comment: What is the meaning of an anonymous class if you need to define the class before using creating the anonymous class

Comment: @tom You don't "need" to define a base class, you can make an anonymous class that extends `Object`. However, any method or field that is not exposed by the base class is hidden at compile time because your class is not named.

It is mainly used to extend already existing interfaces and abstract classes for use in 1 variable. This way you can have quick concrete implementations. Look into how iterators can be implemented, for instance.